# What is the right way to add app.config to a .net core wpf application since it doesn't come with it unlike .net framework?

Tags: c#, wpf

I like setting my connection string in my app.config and this has been very easy for me for a .net framework. Since I migrated to .net core I noticed that it doesn't come with app.config.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core and ASP.NET Core applications the application settings are stored in a JSON file named appsettings.json. This is the default configuration for .NET Core projects. INI and XML files is also supported but JSON is the default.
You may also added to .Net Core WPF project appsettings.json config file, for this you need to install following nuget packegs:

```
  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

after this,

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDataBaseConnectionString": "Server=myServer;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

and you can read it in your code by calling the GetConnectionString method in the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration namespace.

```
var myDbConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("myDataBaseConnectionString");
```

Second way, you may use static class for keeping your database connection data:

```
public static class dbConfig
    {
        public const string ConnectionString =
            "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = TCP)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.100.10.11)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = testdb))); User Id =admin; Password=admin;Pooling=true";
    }
```

and you may use from it any place of your assambly